# Field Missing from Aggregate Fields in Roll-Up

Tags: opportunity, roll-up-summary

[image]Just trying to implement a roll-up summary field that will look at closed won opportunities against an account and show the sum of the amount. When I get into the roll-up field creation I have selected summarised object = opportunities, roll-up type = SUM and field to aggregate should = amount (currency field) but this is not available for selection.

The criteria for records is opp stage = closed won after this.

Any ideas why the amount field is not available here?

Thanks

Comment: `Opportunity` and `Account` are not it Master-Detail relationships

Comment: @Oleksiy can you explain more how can it be possible? OP says he can able to choose Opportunity object from the list

Comment: @SantanuBoral Ugh, these are special.

Comment: It should be available. Did you scroll through the items presented? Did you rename it. Is the field visible to your profile?

Comment: As @Eric mentioned please check the field visibility settings for your profile.

Comment: @Oleksiy - just a heads up I have been looking into this for ages and found this; "However, if you enable advanced currency management, you can’t create roll-up summary fields that calculate currency on the opportunity object rolling up to the account object". That's what we have so guess it can't be done!

Answer (score 3):

For currency fields such as Amoount on Opportunity to come up in 'Field to Aggregate', please make sure 'Advanced Currency Management' is DISABLED in Manage Currencies from Setup.

I disabled this setting and all the currency fields in Opportunity was visible in Account rollup summary.

Thanks